# Firebase: User has to be verificated every time, it runs the application

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, verification

I am working on an android application, where currently I am trying to implement an authentication function with the usage of Firebase.

The functionalities work as they should, the user can log in both ways I expect, but every time it opens the program, has to go through an authentication procedure. Also, after clicking on the log off button, the system also drops up the google-verification immediately. (after avoiding it, we finally get to the menu with the login stuff again, but it is very annoying this way)

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 7117;
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;
Button logout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

    logout = v.findViewById(R.id.logout);
    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .signOut(getActivity())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            logout.setEnabled(false);
                            showSignOptions();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    providers = Arrays.asList(
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()    
    );

    showSignOptions(); 
    return v;
}

private void showSignOptions() {
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .setLogo(R.drawable.loginlogo)
                    .setTheme(R.style.LogInTheme)
                    .build(), MY_REQUEST_CODE
    );
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            logout.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + response.getError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my opinion the `FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` should be the line which causes the problem, but not sure how to solve it (I mean of course, if it is the problem...)

Is there any way to block the system for asking for verification if the user once logged in, as long as it logs out? - also when it logs out, get back to the login intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try that; in `onStart()` method in your launcher activity, you can check whether the user is logged in or not. you can do something like that

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in, go to home activity/fragment.
} else {
    // No user is signed in, go to signin acitvity/fragment.
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. In this way, the system would still execute the verification. Also at the `onStart()`, you mean I should replicate the login-intent builder again for the scenario if the user is null?

Comment: in my case, I used a splash screen activity as the launcher for my application. and in the ```onCreate``` method I would check if the user is logged in or not. if the user is logged in I start the home activity, if the user is not logged in I start the signin activity. let me know if you need more explanations. @Zolly

Comment: you can do the same in the activity which holds your fragment. if you are still stuck let me know @Zolly

Comment: You were right. I separated the login to a completely new activity, also set up a little user-check, and it works as it should. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome. I think there would be a better way to do that, in case  I find a better clean way. I am going to add another answer... happy coding!